# String to time - convert eregi_replace to preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, eregi

Now I'm using function `eregi_replace()` which is deprecated and I want to convert it to function `preg_match()`. Now I have this:

```
foreach ($lesson as $key => $val) {
    $lesson_time[$key]->fromTime = eregi_replace('([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '\1:\2',$val->fromTime);
}
```

where input ($val->fromTime) is string for example `0830` or `1150` and output is 08:30 or `11:50`. I'm not good with regex so I would like to ask how this function with the same process can be convert to preg_match().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/', $val->fromTime, $match);

print_r($match);
```

You can't replace string with preg_match. You can use preg_replace.

```
preg_replace('/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/', '$1:$2', $val->fromTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo preg_replace('/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/', '\\1:\\2',$val->fromTime);
```

Comment: `\1` is invalid syntax in replacement. Should be `\\1` or `$1`

Answer (score 1):

```
$lesson_time[$key]->fromTime = eregi_replace('/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/','$1:$2',$val->fromTime);
```